# Adobe Animate - Populate Combobox select with JSON

Tags: javascript

Using the following to populate a combobox select with JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/get_patients.php"
}).then(function (data) {
    assignDataF(data);
})

function assignDataF(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#patients_cbx').
        append($("<option/>").attr("value", i).text(data[i].label));
    }
}
```

The combobox just shows 70 empty select options, no data.

The JSON:

```
[{"data":"1","label":"Joe Walsh"},{"data":"2","label":"Don Henley"}]
```

[image]

I can populate a dynamic text field OK with the same JSON source.

The comboxbox options appear to almost equal the length of the JSON in characters...

Comment: _"The comboxbox options appear to almost equal the length of the JSON in characters..."_ - probably because `data` is seen as a _text_ value, so that you are looping over this character by character ... Unless your server returns a Content-Type header that says this response _is_ JSON, you will either have to specify the expected return type in your $.ajax options, or you have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by CBroe, I needed to specify the data type in the AJAX.  This now works as expected.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/get_patients.php",
    dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (data) {
    assignDataF(data);
})


function assignDataF(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#patients_cbx').
        append($("<option/>").attr("value", i).text(data[i].label));
    }
}
```